# Python - Data manipulation in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm at the stage where I've a txt file in the form:

```
text1;10;20;11
text2;3;4;5
text3;4;5;7
```

Anyone got any idea what function to use to get rid of the numbers in the middle of each line?
I would like to have in output:

```
text1;11
text2;5
text3;7
```

Currently I have done:

```
    for ii in files:
        if ii.endswith(".txt"):  # only txt files
            with open(ii, 'r') as f:
                content = f.read()
                f.close()
                content1 = re.sub('\t', '', content, flags=re.M)
                content2 = re.sub(' ', '', content1, flags=re.M)
                f = open(ii, "w+")
                f.write(content2)
                f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you open the file get the data manipulation it and write the file back

```
file_name ="/content/untitled" 
list_res=[]
with open(file_name ,"r") as f:
  while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
      break
    list_t = line.split(";")
    list_res.append(f"{list_t[0]};{list_t[-1]}")
print(list_res)
with open(file_name ,"w") as f:
  f.write("".join(list_res))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the String with the split method and get the first and last element together

```
s = "text1;10;20;11"
result = s.split(";")[0] + ";" + s.split(";")[-1]
```

output will be text1;11

Answer (score 0):

To complete Mario Khoury's answer, I'd point out that you don't need to open/close the file you want to read/write to within `with open(ii, 'r') as f:`.

what do you want to do? Create another file with only the start/end elements of each line, or replace the lines in the original file? File handling depends on what you want to do.

```
for ii in files:
        if ii.endswith(".txt"):  # only txt files
            with open(ii, 'r') as f, open(output_file, 'w') as f_out:
                content = f.read()
                res = content.split(";")[0] + ";" + content.split(";")[-1]
                f_out.write(res)
```

Comment: 's' is not defined

Comment: You're right I copied and pasted Mario's answer a little bit too fast! Thanks @tomerar

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['text1;10;20;11','text2;3;4;5','text3;4;5;7']
for i in a:
  s=i.split(';')
  print(s[0] + ';' + s[-1])
```

Output:

```
text1;11
text2;5
text3;7
```